Connecting multiple sound devices to Ubuntu 22.04 and Jack
For a musical project I need 3 inputs with phantom. Unfortunately, I only have one Motu UltraLite AVB with 2 ins, and a Zoom F3 with 2 ins. So, I thought: why not trying to use the inputs of both cards together?
Is it possible to connect two cards to my Ubuntu 22.04 and use their inputs arbitrarily? Could someone describe how to do that?
I have the following configuration:
I add a sound card -- I start QJackCtl -- I open QJackCtl's "Graph", and connect the outputs of the system (ins) to the inputs of Reaper -- Then I connect the outputs of Reaper to the inputs of system (exit)
